# Ember's transitionToRoute slug with a new entity

Tags: url, ember.js, controller, entity, slug

This is my router:

```
this.resource('catalog', function(){
    this.route('products'),
    this.route('product', {path: 'product/:id'})
});
```

`catalog/products` is an overview of all products. If one clicks on one product, you get transitioned to `catalog/product/123` whereas `123` is the id of the product. At the overview there is also a `New product` button, where you can create a new product. In my code I have the following transition behind this button:

```
actions: {
    new: function(){
        this.transitionToRoute('catalog.product', null);
    }
}
```

The URL is then: `catalog/product/undefined` and I thought everything is fine, because there is no id as this product is new and will be saved later. But my `setupController` of the `CatalogProductRoute` says something different:

```
setupController: function(controller, model){
    var productId = model.id;
    if(productId){
        console.log('product exists with id: ' + productId);
    } else {
        console.log('product does not exist');
    }
}
```

Unfortunately `productId` has the value `undefined` and therefore the first if-clause is true, but I thought it was something like null, as I handed over null in the `transitionToRoute`. How can I solve this? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty model will probably be problematic down the road.  It's probably better to have a good separation of concerns between viewing a product and creating a product.

You might consider changing the router to something along these lines:

```
this.resource('catalog', function(){
    this.resource('products', function(){
      this.route('product', {path: ':id'})
      this.route('create');
    }),
});
```

Then when you are creating, you are on this endpoint:

```
/products/create
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/701/edit

Comment: Mh... What's the matter about creating a new controller and route for this? Why? There are a lot of frameworks which handle creation and editing (= view) of an entity in the same controller function. They separate between both cases if an id is given or not. Furthermore, I thought that I read somewhere that this case is possible with ``null``... Did they change it?

Comment: @tester You should try to shed your past experience in this case and go with this pattern. It will properly structure your base resource collection and then your urls. For example `products/1` (this is the "product" route ), `products/create`, `products/delete`, etc.

Comment: I was really saying creating versus viewing.  Ember makes sharing pieces so easy, it just doesn't seem idiomatic to me.  I'm actually surprised your code doesn't crash :) If model is undefined, `var productId = model.id;` should blow chunks.

Comment: Okay, but this seems odd to me. I mean what if I don't want to use special URLs just for creation/deletion etc.? :-)

Comment: You can always programmatically set the model and not have it be part of the url.  It just means that you passing around a url, or bookmarking a url would be broken.

Comment: Okay... I found another way: ``if(typeof productId !== 'undefined'){
        console.log('product exists with id: ' + productId);
    } else {
        console.log('product does not exist');
    }`` This works like expected. Don't know if this is good, but it works.